# SAS Batch Submission -- Prevent truncation at 256 characters per line?

Tags: sas

I have 1000+ .sas files that I am trying to run in batch (all the code in each file is on one line), but SAS truncates the line to 256 characters and the code fails.  Running each file individually (outside the batch) works fine.

Is there a way around this that would not force me to open each file and manually change the length of each line to something SAS can handle?

Comment: In addition to my answer, I'd strongly consider doing things differently, if you can.  I obviously don't know what you're doing that might require 1000s of separate programs, each with a single very long line of code, but not many tasks should require such an approach.  It might be worth it to consider whether there is a simpler approach to your problem that only requires one or a few programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to SAS 9.2, you can't extend the line limit in a batch file.  You can extend the line limit in an %include, though, using the LRECL option; one option is to do so and have your batch submission all in one file with a bunch of %includes.

If you are running SAS 9.2 or later, you have the LRECL system option, which allows up to 32767 characters per line.  See [this page](http://support.sas.com/kb/15/883.html) for more information.